# WordPress 'The following link has expired'

Tags: database, wordpress, error-handling

I've got a big problem. I am working on a site within wordpress when I was doing so compressions etc this morning and I go back onto my site to see the theme options have been reset! So I tried to go into change them but every time i try to save it comes up with this.

[The Following Link Has Expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOakq.png)

I'm really confused. I think it's more of a database issue because I've contacted my hosting company and they did everything they could but still nothing.

I have followed every single tutorial online and nothing. Can anyone help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my own mistake! - What I had done is while minifying the CSS files I accidentally minified the theme's style.css file. In order for WordPress theme's to work they need the Theme Info at the top. So, just add back in the info and it all works!

Hope this can help to anyone if they're having the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to update your php settings to include something like the following:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M

post_max_size = 64M

max_execution_time = 300
```

Change the numbers accordingly.

Here's some reference: https://superpctricks.com/the-link-you-followed-has-expired-wordpress-error/

Comment: The thing is I'm not running c-panel... I'm running off FastHosts